# Xamarin Android - Image to Text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have found this code:

```
// provide read access to the file
FileStream fs = new FileStream(media.Path, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
// Create a byte array of file stream length
byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
//Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
fs.Read(ImageData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
//Close the File Stream
fs.Close();
string _base64String = Convert.ToBase64String (ImageData);
```

I'm not sure how to pass in an image and which imports to use to get it working. I basically want to take an image and convert it to text.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "take an image and convert it to text?" You mean read text in an image? Doing that is significantly more complicated than what you have here.

Comment: No, I need to convert an image to text so I can store it in a database.

Comment: the first argument, media.Path, is the file path to an image

Comment: How would I assign an image to the value media then? Sorry, I'm still very new to xamarin and c#.

Comment: If you want to store it in a database why don't you store it as a blob ?

Comment: If you think that's better how would I do that? Sorry again. I've managed to get the db with mysql working so I'm not completely hopeless.

Comment: Why would you want to store an image in a DB at all? An image is binary data. Just store the path/filename in the database and keep the image in the filesystem; filesystems are _pretty good_ for storing files...

Comment: I don't know any other way of uploading an image to a remote server. I've tried researching it but no luck? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend storing images in a blob file.
But if you really want to store them in a string you can achieve it with the following code snippets

**To string**

```
byte[] ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Path to the image to load");
        string _base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
```

**To byteArray**

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(_base64String);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"Path to the image to store", data);
```

Comment: That's brilliant, how would I reference an image for example in the DCIM? What would the path for that look like?

Comment: You could use System.Environment.GetFolderPath

Comment: Sorry, again. How would I use that to get a specific directory? Thanks for your help though. I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: With the Environment.GetFolderPath you could het a base folder

Comment: Again, I'm pathetic, what would the file path for that look like? E.g. in Windows it's C:\... What would it be in Android? Could you possibly give me a sample snippet. Thanks though I'm nearly there!

Comment: string Dir = Path.Combine(Environment.DirectoryPictures, "MyPhoto.png");

Comment: I've tried:

            string Dir = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures, "img.jpg");

            //byte[] ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/img.jpg");

of which only the first doesn't error but then nothing is outputted to SysLog.